# Intel PRIME profile causes freezing on boot

Tags: release-loki, boot, nvidia, intel

After a new installation of Loki 0.4.1, the system boots fine but has some issues with freezing on booting and suspending. As per discussions, installing the proprietary nVidia drivers provided through the AppCenter fixes this issue.

However, once installed, the PRIME profile is by default on `nvidia`. Changing this to `intel` via `sudo prime-select intel` on the command line, or through the `nvidia-settings` gui, and then rebooting, causes the system to freeze.

This freeze occurs after the elementaryos logo on boot. Removing `quiet slash` from grub to see what's going on reveals a single `failed` status item:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
See 'systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service' for details.
```

This particular issue is fixed following suggestions [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-persistenced/+bug/1693123).

Once fixed, the boot sequence reveals no `failed` items, but there remains no change in the freezing behavior. The system is unresponsive to any commands and requires a hard reset.

Booting into recovery mode and switching back to `nvidia` via `sudo prime-select nvidia` at the command line allows the user to reboot back into gpu-mode, but at the cost of losing access to the intel power-saving mode (e.g. fans constantly running, etc.)

This is occurs on a Razer Blade v4 with GTX 970m and Intel i7–6700HQ.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stumbled across a solution that seems to work. The problem seems to stem from the fact that if the discrete Nvidia GPU is switched off before starting Xorg, the system freezes.

The GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/r0l1/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix) provides a way to manually disable/enable the discrete card after starting the graphical session.

I followed a different [set of instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jI2jlVi1V0H8SeNm5kspJ1qXVtibLOnxNOkDr8ExoSI/edit#heading=h.ji4tc8troxq) reiterated below:

```
$ sudo apt install git cpio iasl
$ git clone https://github.com/m4ng0squ4sh/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix
$ cd razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix
$ sudo make all && sudo make install
```

Then, modify a boot-time config file

```
$ sudo vim  /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

There is a block of code around line 200 that reads something like

```
EOF
    fi
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
        initrd  ${intel_ucode} ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
```

or

```
EOF
    fi
    sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/" << EOF
        initrd  ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
```

Edit the line last line to read

```
initrd  ${rel_dirname}/razer_acpi_fix.img ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
```

or

```
initrd  ${rel_dirname}/razer_acpi_fix.img ${intel_ucode} ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
```

depending on the original construction.

Saving the file, ensuring I'm on the intel profile with `sudo prime-select intel`, updating the grub with `sudo update-grub`, and finally rebooting seems to avoid the system locking up.